# what happens within run() but outside of handlers?/where should send() be placed?

Tags: websocket++

I want to `send` messages whenever I want. However, I don't know where to put `send()`. I don't actually know what happens after `run()` is called but not inside a handler.

My current setup is just to `send` my message in `on_open` because that's the only place I could put `send` to get it to work. However, sending multiple messages this way is proving to be a problem. I can close the connection from `on_message`, but I am unable to `send` again via that client, regardless of if I `connect` or `run()` again.

The ideal solution would be to not have to `close` and reopen the connection or the endpoint. Again, I would like to know where I should put `send` if not in `on_open` or `on_message`

```
c.init_asio();
c.start_perpetual();//I've tried both perpetual and non-perpetual 

//[associate handlers]

c.connect(con); //connecting and running works fine;
c.run();        //on_open, on_message work fine
sleep(15);      //is 15 seconds enough for the asio to clean up everything?
c.connect(con); //any permutation of these two lines
c.run();        //do  nothing after close() has been called
std::string test("test");
con->send(test,websocketpp::frame::opcode::TEXT); //this does nothing
```

using C++11 and VS2015. Also I'm not able to copy/paste the code, so I may have missed some dumb typos.Not sure what else to say. I don't know where I can put `send`  so that I can send it upon a buttonpress, for example

Comment: Is your `c.run();`  wraps `io_context.run() `?

Comment: if so......`c.run();        //on_open, on_message work fine`
`sleep(15);      //is 15 seconds enough for the asio to clean up everything?`

try reset the io_context.reset() here.

`c.connect(con);`
`c.run(); `

Comment: from this line `init_asio()`, I presuppose that you are using boost.asio and your question is relates to boost.asio.

Comment: @Explorer_N it says "wraps the run method of the internal io_service object." this is not my ```run()```  but websocket++'s ```run()```.  I tried using ```c.reset()``` before ```sleep``` and it does say "successful connection," but nothing else happens. I re-associated the handlers, but they don't activate the second time.

Comment: websocket++. Sounds like a library. "I tried using c.reset() before sleep" it has to be after `sleep` and before `c.connect(con)`, first of all, why do you need `sleep` and multiple `run`?

Comment: yes it's a library. it's hard to answer your question because I don't know what I need. I put sleep there because it's an asynchronous scheme. it requires time to release resources or something. I put the second ```run``` to try to trigger the on_open handler again

Comment: That library wraps boost.asio, so from asio experience, what I can tell you is, use single run. when you call `run()` it will block till all the async operation you've initiated is complete.

Answer (score 0):

When using WebSocket++ with the Asio based transport, the `endpoint::run` method is just a convenience wrapper around Asio's `io_service.run()`. There is extensive documentation for Asio about how this works if you want a lot of detail.

In short, `run` will block indefinitely while performing an event based network I/O loop and will not return until the connection completes.

Sending messages can be done from within that event loop by responding to the various handlers. As you note you can send messages from the open handler. Another common handler to send messages from is the message handler, which would allow you to reply to any message the remote endpoint sent. If you want to send a message independently of network events (open, message received, etc) you can use an interrupt handler (trigger a new event asap) or the timer handler (trigger a new event after a period of time) or set up a thread to send messages whenever you need.

The bundled `telemetry_server` example demonstrates the timer approach and the `telemetry_client` example demonstrates the threaded one.